# Ruby - examine contents of Queue without emptying it?

Tags: ruby, queue

Ruby has a [`Queue` class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Queue.html) with just a few methods: `push`, `pop`, `length`, `empty?`, `clear`, `close`, `closed?`, and `num_waiting`. (Plus synonyms.)

I don't see a way to examine the contents of a queue object without popping them — perhaps because the `Queue` class is intended for use with threads rather than other objects.

Or am I mistaken? Is there a way to examine the contents of a queue object without popping them?

Comment: There does not seem to be such method.

Answer (score 1):

`Queue` class does not have peek functionality.

If you can manage thread-safety issues, you can make use of `Array` to act like a Queue.

```
 q = Array.new
 q.push 1
 q.push 2
 q.push 3

 q.shift # Equivalent of Queue#pop
 #=> 1

 q.first # Equivalent to peek
 #=> 2

 q.first(2)
 #=> [2, 3]
```

Comment: `Array`, however, has linear time-complexity for right-end `shift`; `Queue.pop` appears to be O(1).

Comment: @brannerchinese  Queue internally uses `Array#shift` for implementing `Queue#pop`.  - Please use `Toggle code` option at [Queue#new documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-c-new) and you will notice that `@que = []` has been used - which maintains internal state.   `Queue` seems to be adding just thread synchronization on top of regular Array